# Touchscreen 14" Gaming Laptop with DVD or BD?

Tags: laptop

By "gaming laptop", I mean a quad-core Skylake CPU with an NVIDIA graphics card... I'm not looking for a Haswell CPU or an Intel graphics card. (I'm not actually planning on using it for gaming, but I do want similar specs for other things I do.)

Does such a thing exist? I've been looking for one, but it seems that I cannot find any that meets all of the conditions. The best I've found is the 2016 Razer Blade which doesn't have an optical drive.

Comment: (i) You must ask yourself the question: how many times do I need the DVD/BD drive? I have an Alienware 13 without a DVD/BD drive. The few times I actually need a drive (e.g. installing old software), I share one from my dektop in my local network. (ii) Furthermore, you should definitely look at heat, cooling and noise issues (e.g. thermal throttling) when considering small laptops with non-integrated GPUs. (iii) The Razor Blade is indeed an ultra-portable, very powerful machine, but keep in mind that it has no Ethernet port (still faster than wireless).

Comment: @Matthias: I didn't know it didn't have an ethernet port... Do you know of a similar one that does? I'm not concerned about noise/heating issues, my current Haswell laptop has the same exact kinds of features I want except a touchscreen and I absolutely love it; I even have my hands on another laptop without the DVD drive and I like it less. It's just that my current laptop is about to break soon so I'm on the lookout for another one.

Comment: 14 inch + gtx 970M + quad-core i7 + ethernet -> exist according to my knowledge, but + touch screen -> didn't find one

Comment: You should also take a look at this: http://www.pcgamer.com/nvidia-geforce-gtx-1070-and-1080-coming-to-gaming-notebooks/